# Fancybox jQuery link to external page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, lightbox

I may be asking a noob question here, but I can't seem to find the answer.

I've set up fancybox and it's working like a charm. I'm calling external pages into the iframe functionality. On the pages (I load into the lightbox) there's a contact page link. When I click it the contact page loads in the iframe.

When clicking the "contact link" I want to close the lightbox and go to the contact page.

Could someone help me? thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your link is like such: `<a href="contact.php">Contact Page</a>`.
If so, try changing it to the following: `<a onClick="closeFBContact()" style="cursor: pointer;">Contact Page</a>`

What this code will do is make a link to a Javascript function instead of an actual page.  I also threw in some cursor styling to make your `a` tag still look like a clickable hyperlink.

From there, go to your main Javascript file where you initialized Fancybox and write the following:

```
function closeFBContact() {
    $.fancybox.close; //This will close the Fancybox window
    window.open("contact.php"); //This will change the page to contact.php
}
```

Check out [Fancybox's API](http://fancybox.net/api) for more information on their public methods.  This should be of some help to you when working with that plugin.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! the only thing I needed to change was to target the javascript in the parent (of the lightbox)

Answer (score 2):

Just put target="_parent" on the link and it will work like a charm. It will also probably be the first time you ever used it in your life.